# I want to simplify my sum query using loop function

Tags: mysql, query, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench, dbeaver

I have a query to summerize my data based on month between year 2021 - next years (depend on the real date)
i used simple query like this to summerize the amount monthly

```
SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2101%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JANUARI,
SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2102%', pt.amount, 0)) AS FEBRUARI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2103%', pt.amount, 0)) AS MARET, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2104%', pt.amount, 0)) AS APRIL, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2105%', pt.amount, 0)) AS MEI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2106%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JUNI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2107%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JULI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2108%', pt.amount, 0)) AS AGUSTUS, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2109%', pt.amount, 0)) AS SEPTEMBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2110%', pt.amount, 0)) AS OKTOBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2111%', pt.amount, 0)) AS NOVEMBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2111%', pt.amount, 0)) AS DESEMBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2201%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JANUARI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2202%', pt.amount, 0)) AS FEBRUARI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2203%', pt.amount, 0)) AS MARET, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2204%', pt.amount, 0)) AS APRIL, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2205%', pt.amount, 0)) AS MEI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2206%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JUNI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2207%', pt.amount, 0)) AS JULI, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2208%', pt.amount, 0)) AS AGUSTUS, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2209%', pt.amount, 0)) AS SEPTEMBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2210%', pt.amount, 0)) AS OKTOBER, SUM(IF(pt.description like '%O-2211%', pt.amount, 0)) AS NOVEMBER FROM platform.mtr_user mu  
left join `transaction`.pg_trx pt on pt.mtr_user_id = mu.id   
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(pt.tags, '"purchase"', '$') and pt.status = '1' and pt.description -> '$.callback_sales' is not null
-- and mu.email = 'carolinesuhartono1979@gmail.com' 
GROUP BY mu.email   
order by pt.order_id limit 100;



but i think this query is not dynamic query.
maybe someone can help me to make a simple looping query.
```

Comment: While pivot table like expressions look like the presentation, even with this small example shows the complexity of the expression. If data was returned in a month per row it wouldn't need to be dynamic. `LIKE` expressions on a `description` is horribly unstructured data and if a date field is in the table that would be much cleaner. Welcome to DBA stack exchange.

Comment: Use synthetic table which generates (months) numbers list from 1 to 11 (or maybe 12?) and use it as one more base data source. Also use another synthetic table which generates years numbers list.

Comment: so no need to make this query much more simple then my current query @danblack?

i can't do that sir @Akina, because the table already created on production.
is there any other suggestion?

Comment: And `LIKE '%...'` is inefficient.  And burying information in JSON is inefficient.  And after moving things to columns you will be able to make use of `INDEXes`.